# Getting the location from a lat/lon parameter

Tags: android, ios, cocoa-touch, geolocation

Looking at doing an app that uses the phones location service and from what I understand the current location is returned in lat/lon.

What is the best method to turn this into a location and/or find the nearest "post office" for example to where they are?

I know you can pass in lat/lon to the google maps API and get a location but is this the best method or is there something better?

Comment: You can use google [library][1] or u can still use any api u can find it  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968592/getting-location-name-using-latitude-and-longitude-value-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) and the method *getFromLocation*

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
// create geo point
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lattitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
// get the MapController object
MapController controller = mapview.getController();
// animate to the desired point
controller.animateTo(point);
```