# How to Get City Name by Latitude &Longitude in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, location

I want to city name by current location but i have latitude and longitude.how to get it? i used button click then i get double value latitude and longitude. my code in below.please help me.

Thanks!!

```
Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{

                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
```

I edited below code but not get cityname please help me !!!

```
Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;
    String CityName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(
                            AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, Locale
                                    .getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    try {
                        Log.v("log_tag", "latitude" + latitude);
                        Log.v("log_tag", "longitude" + longitude);
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                                longitude, 1);
                        Log.v("log_tag", "addresses+)_+++" + addresses);
                        CityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        Log.v("log_tag", "CityName" + CityName);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude
                                    + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {

                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
```

But I get Error in below::::

```
03-11 17:01:46.465: W/System.err(27587): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
03-11 17:01:46.465: W/System.err(27587):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
03-11 17:01:46.465: W/System.err(27587):    at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:81)
03-11 17:01:46.465: W/System.err(27587):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-11 17:01:46.475: W/System.err(27587):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 17:02:21.335: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27587): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-11 17:02:21.335: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27587): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-11 17:02:21.425: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27587): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: Refer [this][1] question and it's answer



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968592/getting-location-name-using-latitude-and-longitude-value-in-android

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use This:

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);
 String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
 String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

For more in detailed google map example you check the links below:
http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/load-googlemap_107

And for the background location updates:
http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/download-android-background-location-update-service-demo_21

Comment: I think @Mayank Saini 's answer is more suitable if one wants to get specifics. Address lines can end up containing more information than necessary (like the sub locality).
'addresses.get(0).getCountryName()` will help get the country name as well.

Comment: If you only want the city name then you should use `addresses.get(0).getLocality()` instead, `addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)` might give you more information additionally to your city name based on the address (Read the `Geocoder` Documentation). but the Locality gives you exactly the cityName. :)

Comment: Dont use geocoder. It will throw exceptions on lot many devices.

Comment: @kiShan it's getting issue ni some device not found city?  Can you help me..

Comment: Some time geocoder returns null value. You can check the result and call again for the result.

Answer (score 28):

On your onClick add this:

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Comment: Log your latitude and longitude and check if they are coming 0.

Answer (score 15):

```
gps = new LocationAddress(getActivity());
if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
  double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
  double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
  Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
  //List<Address> addresses =geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

  try {
    List < Address > addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    String address = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
    String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    txt_paddress.setText(address);
    txt_city.setText(cityName);
    txt_state.setText(stateName);

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} else {
  gps.showSettingsAlert();
}
```

Comment: Some explanation will be great, please edit your answer

Answer (score 7):

Use this and pass your lat long values to it.

```
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder. getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();else return NULL
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yesm but `getLocality()` can be null for some cases

Answer (score 4):

For my country (Vietnam) `getLocality` will return null and `addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)` will return the **district not city**

So I will do like this

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

int maxAddressLine = addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();

String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(maxAddressLine);
String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(maxAddressLine-1);
String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(maxAddressLine-2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Geocoder. Pass the latitude and longitude and get city name and address.

```
try {

    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List < Address > addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
        addres.setText("Waiting for Location");
    } else {
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            addres.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only need to show country and city name, so I am using following code 
Here I am using "en" for always showing country and city name in English language instead of users regional language. Otherwise you can `Locale.getDefault()` method.

```
 double latitude = location.getLatitude();
 double longitude = location.getLongitude();

 Locale locale = new Locale("en"); //OR Locale.getDefault()

 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, locale);
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

 updatedCity = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

 if (updatedCity == null) {
     updatedCity = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
 }

 updatedCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
```

Answer (score 0):

none any of answer above solve my case

for case in Indonesia, you can call `addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea()` to get city name

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin example:

```
private fun getCityNameWithLocation(lat: Double, long: Double) {
        val geocoder = Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale.getDefault())
        val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, long, 1)
        if(addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
            val cityName: String = addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)
            Timber.d("cityName: $cityName")
        }
    }
```